# Why Android is leaking window in extended activity for dialog created in super activity even dismiss is called?

Tags: java, android, exception, memory-leaks

I am working on an Android project. I have `BaseActivity` which extends `AppCompatActivity` and than I have another activity `StartActivity` which extends `BaseActivity`. I have AlertDialog in BaseActivity that I am calling.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_attention));
        alertDialog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.message_permission_denied));

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.button_settings), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent myAppSettings = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                        Uri.parse("package:" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()));

                myAppSettings.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                myAppSettings.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                getApplicationContext().startActivity(myAppSettings);
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.button_exit),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                aDialog.dismiss();
                finish();

            }
        });
        aDialog = alertDialog.create();

        aDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                aDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorButtonPositive));
                aDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorButtonNegative));
            }
        });

        if (!aDialog.isShowing())
            aDialog.show();
```

And I am also overriding `onDestroy` method in BaseActivity,

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
        try{
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (aDialog != null && aDialog.isShowing()) {
                        aDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e){
            new ErrorPrinter(e.toString());
        }
    }
```

StackTrace/Error logs,

```
01-13 08:38:59.928 5501-5501/com.company.android E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.company.android.activities.StartActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{7a59bc1 V.E...... R......D 0,0-1160,413} that was originally added here
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:368)
                                                                                        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:299)
                                                                                        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                                                                                        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:319)
                                                                                        at com.company.android.activities.BaseActivity.permissionDenied(BaseActivity.java:216)
                                                                                        at com.company.android.activities.BaseActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(BaseActivity.java:160)
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:6582)
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6460)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3695)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3742)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1393)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

But I am getting exception in Android Monitor that StartActivity has leaked window that was originally added here. Can anyone tell me how can I solve this error?

The reason I am extending to BaseActivity is that I want to use some of the feature for all the activities so I can write or remove codes for one time and it will be used in all activities.

Thanks.

Comment: post your stacktrace so we can see where the problem lies

Answer (score 0):

Its due to when the activity is paused, it is garbage collected but as the dialog is still not dismissed, alert dialog still has a reference to the activity.

You need to override onPause() and onStop() in your BaseActivity:

```
@Override
  public void onPause() {
      super.onPause();

      if(aDialog != null)
          aDialog.dismiss();
  }

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    if(aDialog != null)
        aDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Also dismiss the dialog and finish activity after this line in `alertDialog.setPositiveButton()` as the other activity is started:

```
getApplicationContext().startActivity(myAppSettings);
aDialog.dismiss();
finish();
```

Comment: try overriding onStop() too

Comment: Your updated codes, `onPause`, `onStop` and also I have `onDestroy` overridden but it is still leaking from extended activity which is `StartActivity`.

Comment: check whether ur dialog context is not null before u call show

Comment: @AmeyShirke It is failing when I click on negative button which is for `Exit` option.

Comment: try saving ur dialog refernce as weakreference , and then use this weakreference to use ur dialog

Comment: @PythonProgrammer try putting aDialog = null; after aDialog.dismiss();

Comment: Tried that too @AmeyShirke but didn't work. It is leaking in `StartActivity` which is extended activity.

Answer (score 0):

I had to override `finish()` method and kill my process by getting process id.

```
@Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    }
```

Thank you all for the help and support!